# Cannot create ActiveX component.Error while using GetObject in autocad 2011

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am using below code to use autocad object.

```
Dim acadapp As AcadApplication

acadapp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")
```

'''and using below code to create object -------------

```
acadapp = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")
```

Getting error "Cannot create ActiveX component".
I tried using 18,19 and various combination as below :

```
acadapp = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application.18")
```

But nothing work.
Please help.

**@Locke : Thanks for reply.I tried your soltion as below :**

```
Dim acadType As Type

Try
   acadapp =   
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.18.1")
   ''Above code din't worked so tried below code also
    ' acadapp = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application.18.1"), 
    'AcadApplication)

Catch ex As Exception           
  acadType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AutoCAD.Application")
  acadapp = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(acadType, True), AcadApplication)           
End Try
```

**Showing Exception :**

Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'AutoCAD.AcadApplication'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{8E75D910-3D21-11D2-85C4-080009A0C626}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: The basic check-list is 1: is AutoCad actually installed?  2: is your program running in the correct bitness that matches AutoCad's?  3: what does SysInternal's ProcMon tell you?

Comment: 1) Autocad running properly on my machine.I have written code in VB6 for same.And it working fine. Kingly explain 2 and 3 checklist.

Comment: @HansPassant is talking about 32-bit versus 64-bit in his second point, which after the error you received is the logical step to look at next.  The library you've imported into your Visual Studio project, containing AcadApplication, did you get it from AutoDesk's ObjectArx?  You need to make sure to import the 64-bit or 32-bit versions of the interop libraries (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll, AutoDesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll) based on the bitness of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I typically use when dealing with AutoCAD interop.  It checks for a running instance, and creates a new one if necessary:

```
private static AcadApplication GetAcadApp(string progId)
{
    // Create the return application
    AcadApplication returnApp = null;

    try
    {
        // Try getting a running instance
        returnApp = (AcadApplication)Marshal.GetActiveObject(progId);
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        try
        {
            // Try creating a new instance
            Type acadType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);
            returnApp = (AcadApplication)Activator.CreateInstance(acadType, true);
        }
        catch (COMException)
        {
            // Report failure
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Cannot create object of type \"{0}\"", progId));
        }
    }

    // Return the application
    return returnApp;
}
```

An AcadApplication COM object can be set like this:

```
// Get/create an AutoCAD instance
var acadApp = getAcadApp("AutoCAD.Application.18");
```

Regardless of C# or VB.NET, using Marshal.GetActiveObject and Activator.CreateInstance are probably the better ways to approach this.

Comment: Also, for AutoCAD 2011 I think it should be "AutoCAD.Application.18.1".  Refer here as a guide:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD

Comment: Thanks Locke.I tried solution suggested by you,But it is showing exception.Added in my query please check.

Comment: Check the interop libraries for the correct bitness as indicated in my comment above.  But also see if you get a valid COM object before you try casting it to AcadApplication.

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception, the problem is not the GetActiveObject() call, but that the returned object doesn't support the interface you're looking for. Most likely reason is that your code references a different version of AcadApplication than the one you're getting back from GetActiveObject(). Change your project to reference the COM library version for the returned AutoCAD instance, and it should work fine.